# How to run tab widget class everytime on clicking on to tabs?

Tags: android

I'm using tab class in my application. I noticed that for the first time when i run the application, tab class runs. When i again click on tab, the activity is not running again, it just displays the page that was run previously. Is there any solution to run the activity again and again when i click on tab?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No your Activity onCreate() will not run every time when you change your tabs . So if you want that your activity onCreate() will every time when  change tab then you can implement button in LinearLayout instead of Tab.